# Can't access variables in JSON

Tags: javascript, json

i feel so stupid.
I got this String:

```
var myString = "({"week":{"@attributes": "Some stuff"}});";
```

No i parse it to JSON:

```
var myobject = JSON.parse(myString);
```

and then i'm trying to access it via:

```
myobject.week or myobject["week"]
```

either way isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your input string isn't valid JSON.

Comment: I'm getting this from a api from my university. I thought they are giving me valid JSON. How to correct it? Remove ();?

Comment: Looks like JSONP with a missing function name. How are you getting the data? You might have to pass a `callback` parameter in the URL and create a function with the same name (that's how JSONP  works, look it up).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is not a valid json string. You must remove the () and ;

```
{"week":{"@attributes": "Some s***"}}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't valid javascript:

```
var myString = "({"week":{"@attributes": "Some stuff"}});";
```

because of the invalid use of quotes inside the string.

This would work as a valid javscript string:

```
var myString = '({"week":{"@attributes": "Some stuff"}});';
```

And, if you want to parse it with `JSON.parse()`, you should remove the outer parens and the semicolon like this:

```
var myString = '{"week":{"@attributes": "Some stuff"}}';
var myobject = JSON.parse(myString);
console.log(myobject.week);
```